# How to get URL S3 object using Terraform?

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, terraform

I uploaded my file in a S3 bucket using Terraform. How can I get its URL like S3://bucket/object?

Im going to use

```
output "my_bucket_file_version" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket_object.object.version_id
}
```

but I suppose that it wont be work.

Comment: Can you add the S3 resource block to the question? It's hard to know but I'm guessing you want: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#website_endpoint. Additionally, you would have to use some kind of interpolation for the output you explained you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `s3://` URI scheme is not actually represented in the S3 API and is instead a UI-level detail in some tools that work with S3 buckets. Since the `hashicorp/aws` provider for Terraform is largely just reflecting details from the underlying API, it doesn't currently have any attribute which provides a ready-to-use `s3://` URI.

However, [this URI convention has a documented structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html#accessing-a-bucket-using-S3-format) and so it's possible to build it from parts:

- Literal `s3://` prefix
- Bucket name
- Literal `/` to delimit the object key.
- The object key

To construct this you'll need both the S3 bucket name and the object key. [The `aws_s3_bucket_object` resource type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object) includes attributes for both of those:

```
output "object_s3_uri" {
  value = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket_object.object.bucket}/${aws_s3_bucket_object.object.key}"
}
```

The documentation for the `s3://` URL scheme doesn't mention anything about how to refer to a specific version of an object, so I don't think it's possible to construct a URI for a particular object *version*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you but I had to do some manipulation of the outputs, and I had to enter some information manually, however this will not work if in the future AWS decides to add/change their domain structure (highly-unlikely). You will have to follow AWS domain structure

```
https://<bucket-name>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/<object-key>
```

```
output "url" {
    description = "url of the bucket"
    value       = "https://${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id}.s3.${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.region}.amazonaws.com/index.html"
}
```